# DNN Portal can't authenticate some users

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am using active directory to authenticate users on my DNN portal. It's been working fine but recently it does not allow some of the users into the site. It brings the server error (404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.)

The funny thing is that not all the users are having this problem, only a few does. I checked in my Users table and these users exists and they have both the Registered Users and Subscribers roles.

I am running on DNN 4.7.0.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you open up fiddler, what is the resource that is 404'ing?

Answer (score 0):

can use please check that user belongs to all portals or portal have different user
in dnn if you create a user in one portal than it is not accessible outside of that portal